# How to dynamically access web service c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webserver, httpwebrequest

We all know that one of the easiest way to acess a web service in C# application is by :

1. Right click on References
2. select Add Service Reference give the wsdl address in the address textbox
3. Click Discover and Give my MyWebReference a name
4. Invoke an object : MyWebReference MyObject = new MyWebReference();
5. call the functions by MyObject.Function1();

The above method works very well but It doesn't suite me as the web reference can changes a lot

I'm looking to a way where I can connect to the web reference by creating a class and pass the address , user name and password by parameter

As an exemple for what I'm trying to do is :

```
Class ConnectToWebReference(string link , string userName , string password) 
{ 
   link=www.webreference.asmx 
userName=Santa
password=Clause 

connect to webReference 

creatObject 

return object 

}

object.callmethod();
```

I would appreciate a guide or a tutorial that explain how can I do this type of connection without having to right click and add the web reference manually

Any help is appreciated

Best Regards

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything on your own?

Comment: @RickS Hello , the problem I'm facing is lack of key word, witch means I don't know what to type as a research  key word :( .... I'm little bit lost . I read a tons of tutorial explaining how to creat a web reference bla bla bla but not the way I want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482773/web-service-without-adding-a-reference

Comment: @RickS Gratitude, I will check this carefully