# Can I communicate to a WCF (svcutil) web service using just GET or POST?

Tags: wcf, rest, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have been given access to a WCF/WSDL web service. I first do this:

```
svcutil.exe https://<thedomain>/foo/foo.svc?wsdl
```

to generate the C# class I need. I then plug this class into my C# application and it works fine. **Note that I did not develop this server and cannot change it.**

Question is this:

How can I communicate with this server without svcutil? I prefer to use just REST (GET and POST).

This way I would be able to connect to it from a Linux or Mac machine, not just Windows.

**Update** In my C# code, this is what happens:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpoint =  new EndpointAddress("<address>");
fooClient client = new fooClient(binding, endpoint);
//(fooClient class came from svcutil)
//I now work with fooClient, call methods on it, etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the bindings in use by the service.

The "default" (read: most commonly used) bindings (basicHttp and wsHttp) implement SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 respectively, which means you're talking HTTP to the service, but using a specially crafted XML envelope in which your payload must be wrapped.

When the webHttpBinding is applied, you can talk "plain old XML" or JSON to the service, how to do so depends on the applied UriTemplate.

Note that there's no standardized metadata exchange for REST services (at least not as far as WCF is concerned), so even *if* the service is exposed using a REST binding, the information about how to construct the calls will not be exposed automatically but must instead be documented by the owners explicitly.

Comment: I updated my question. It's using WSHttpBinding. Does this mean it's using SOAP 1.2 as you said? If so, how do I obtain the format of these envelopes? (Unfortunately the envelope format doesn't show up when I visit the service URL in my web browser. Only the instructions to run svcutil.exe show up, followed by some C# code. Is there another way to get the SOAP envelope XML format?)

Comment: It's a bit unclear why you would want to write your own SOAP client. What's wrong with SvcUtil? Anyway the question _"How to write a C# SOAP client using an HTTP client"_ is way too broad to answer, but you can search the web for it.

Comment: @code-ninja-54321 see for example [Web Service without adding a reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482773/web-service-without-adding-a-reference).

Comment: The purpose is to be able to connect to this web service from Mac or Linux. Can't run an exe file on those. Can't use C#/.NET on those either. If I can connect to the service via POST, I can use it on Mac or Linux.

Comment: @code-ninja-54321 so this is not about programming? Then use SoapUI or another SOAP test client? Or craft the XML on beforehand and send it using Curl or WGet. You _can_ run .NET executables on those platforms though.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I have created a more focused question now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039901/converting-a-wcf-svcutil-c-sharp-code-into-the-corresponding-soap-envelope-pos

Answer (score -1):

[REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is an architectural approach. WCF service should be built for REST, not that you just can use it like this. In WCF service "by default" all requests are POSTs.