# c# - Using reporting services without web references

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, sccm

I am working on a project that needs to create folders and upload files to the sql server report services using C#. There is way to do this without adding web references? I would like this because I want a generic approach, probably just knowing the web service URL.

I was trying the following code:

```
static public string CallRemoteWebService()
{
        string ResponseText = "";

        string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8530/ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx ";
        string WebMethodName = "ListEvents";

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:8530/ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx");
            var payload = string.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
  <soap:Body>
    <{0} xmlns=""http://taller-server/Reports2"" />
  </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>", WebMethodName);

            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            var result = client.UploadData(WebServiceUrl, data);

            ResponseText = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);

        }
        return ResponseText;
}
```

But it does not working properly

Sorry if this is an obvious question but I don't have much experience with c# nor reporting services.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The execution of the code throws a WebException, showing "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? What is the error?

Comment: The question I have would be why wouldn't you use a web reference instead of hand-crafting SOAP envelopes?  That is like disconnecting the garden hose so you can put out a fire with buckets.

Comment: Because I will obtain the web service URL on runtime (the address might change, but the services will not).

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482773/web-service-without-adding-a-reference

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need!