# Consume web service dynamically using HttpWebRequest without service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, httpwebrequest

The application I work will have to send data to external system. The system system will have a web service (c# or java or php) and I need to consume it. Since there will be as many external system as clients, I need to get the WSDL file, method name and parameters as user input and send the data to the external system.

So, I am trying to invoke a web service dynamically using code available  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482932/2922388)

I tested few free web services available [here](http://www.service-repository.com)

I find the SOAP location, method name and parameters from the the WSDL file and give the same as input.

The following service works as expected

```
http://soaptest.parasoft.com/calculator.wsdl
Location - http://ws1.parasoft.com/glue/calculator
Method Name - add
Parameter - x,y
```

But when I tried the same for the another free service by providing the SOAP location, and method name it throws 500 Internal server error.

```
http://www.predic8.com:8080/crm/CustomerService?wsdl
Location - http://www.predic8.com:8080/crm/CustomerService
Method Name - getAll
```

I confirmed these inputs are correct by testing the above wsdl in soapUI. The same location is used in soapUI request window.

I am not sure why it throws error. Please help me understand it.

Also please let me know if it is fine to get the service location from WSDL file and use the `HttpWebRequest` to get the response. I am afraid whether this method of invoking the web service will work irrespective the technology used to implement the web service.

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to with the SOAP envelope.

For http://soaptest.parasoft.com/calculator.wsdl even if we ignore xmlns:cal="http://www.parasoft.com/wsdl/calculator/, it gets executed successfully.

But for http://www.predic8.com:8080/crm/CustomerService?wsdl , if I ignore xmlns:ns="http://predic8.com/wsdl/crm/CRMService/1/, it throws internal server error.

Please share how I can be generic here

Comment: Can you please show your request which is causing you the error?

Comment: Tech Jerk, Have you got chance to look at the answer to see if that is helpful?

Comment: The time is over but maybe this link help someone: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/calling-a-web-method-in-c-without-a-service-reference/

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with request data that you are using. The request is failing validation, so is the error.

If you import the provided [wsdl](http://www.predic8.com:8080/crm/CustomerService?wsdl), and validate create request, it is clear what the problem is.

There is an element `id` under `Person` and `Customer` and data must follow certain patter which is defined under the schema `../common/1`

Here is the schema reference, which has `simpleType` **restriction**:

```
   <xsd:simpleType name="IdentifierType">
      <xsd:annotation>
         <xsd:documentation>Identifier for business objects.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]{2}-\d{5}"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
```

So, `id` value should Something like `AA-12345` i.e., two Capital letter, hyphen(-), and followed by 5 digits.

Change your request as per above pattern, and you should be good.

Hope this is helpful.