# Call SOAP service from .Net Core 6 without adding Service Reference

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on a website using .Net Core 6 and I need to communicate with a 3rd party SOAP service.

If I add a reference using a "Service Reference" it causes the solution to restore / include .Net Framework packages, I assume because the SOAP service is written in .Net Framework. References to the restored .Net Framework packages are in the ConnectedService.json file.

Can I use the SOAP service without adding it as a Service Reference, and therefore avoid the references to .Net 4 Framework packages?

An example warning is:

> Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.7' was restored using
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of
> the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully
> compatible with your project.

**Edit:**
I found this which seems like a viable option - [Web Service without adding a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482773/web-service-without-adding-a-reference/9482932#9482932)

Unless there is a better way?

Comment: In my search result, I found another code example for calling SOAP service without adding a service reference. You could refer to [Working With Web Services Without Adding A Reference In C#](https://ehikioya.com/web-services-without-adding-reference/)